# TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER is null in android 9

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-9.0-pie

I am not able to get the caller phone number using TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER in android 9 devices. Its always null. I have added the required permissions in my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

////

```
<receiver android:name="packagename" android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />

        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

////

```
 public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d(" onReceive: ", "flag1");

    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)
            || state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

        Log.d("Ringing", "Phone is ringing");

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

In the above onReceive() method, I have accessed the phone's state which goes well..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW},
                    1);
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l1);
        l1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finishAndRemoveTask();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }
        });
         number = getIntent().getStringExtra(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);


         if (number.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("+")){
            number=number.substring(3);
            Log.e("bbbb",number);
         }
        String state = getIntent().getStringExtra(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        progressBarf = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        mobile_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_number);
        vechile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vechile);
        name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText("Searching");
        mobile_number.setText(number);
        close=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.close);
         db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        if (ConnectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet(MainActivity.this)) {
            makeJsonArrayRequest();

        }else{
            Pojo pp= db.getContact(number);
            progressBarf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Get From Offline",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (pp.getS_vechile().equals("0")){
                name.setText(pp.getS_name());
            }else {
                name.setText(pp.getS_name());
                vechile.setText("("+pp.getS_vechile()+")");
            }
            Log.e("dayalen","aa"+String.valueOf(db.getContactsCount()));
        }
        startService(new Intent(this, UpdateService.class));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UpdateService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent
                .getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // Start service every hour
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                3600*1000, pintent);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finishAndRemoveTask();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here, TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER gives null when call is made. But actually it should return the caller's phone number.

Comment: Please share your code (where you are trying to get this data & where you are asking about permission)

Comment: thanks for the response, I have added the source code.

Comment: @ry. But that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are almost there. What you missing is `READ_CALL_LOG` runtime permission. You need to ask for runtime permission just like the way you did for `READ_PHONE_STATE`.

Comment: Not get output... Please give any other solutions

Comment: How to handle runtime permissions for this case that is not an activity is a class that extends BroadcastReceive?

Comment: If I use the permissions at runtime does that mean that every time I enter a call I will have to accept the permission to get the incoming number? Because that would not be very practical

Comment: int readContactsPermissionLog = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
            if(readContactsPermissionLog != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
            }